# How to access the "arr" or each element from below code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
    def check(abc: true, de: true, fgh: true)

      arr = []

      arr << :ll_de if de
      arr << :ll_de_a2 if de
      arr << :ll_de_kk_fgh if de && fgh

      arr << :ll_abc_hh_de if abc && de
      arr << :ll_abc_hh_de_fgh if abc && de && fgh

      arr
    end



puts check
```

#it's giving all the names(ll_de, ll_de_a2,ll_de_kk_fgh,ll_abc_hh_de, ll_abc_hh_de_fgh)

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Something like `check[0]` or what?

Answer (score 0):

Just assign `check` to a variable, and then access to your heart's content:

```rb
foo = check
foo.each_with_index {|e, i| puts "#{(i+1).ordinalize} element: #{e}" }
```

Comment: we can do it directly by using check.each_with_index etc.. but how to use "arr " here

Comment: You can't get to `arr` from outside the `check` method, its scope is only within that method.